# Set Cron Job on amplify

Tags: firebase, push-notification, aws-amplify

I am working on amplify and using firebase for push notification. Now, I need to schedule notification on particular date and time. I didn't get any solution for this. If anyone knows, Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a cloud function scheduling feature which supports cronjobs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

```js
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 * * * *')
  .timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') // 
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('Running');
  return null;
});
```